# Is there a function in Mathematica to calculate population standard deviation?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

In *Mathematica* there is a function `StandardDeviation` used to calculate the sample standard deviation. I want to know if there is a function to calculate the population standard deviation. From [this book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=k3rkxOURuOMC&pg=PA77), it seems there is a function `StandardDeviationMLE` in older versions of *Mathematica*, which I can't find in *Mathematica* 11. I want to know if this function still exists in the newer versions of *Mathematica*. Thanks guys in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

StandardDeviationMLE  is defined in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Statistics/DescriptiveStatistics.html):

```
StandardDeviationMLE[data_] := 
 StandardDeviation[data] Sqrt[(Length[data] - 1)/Length[data]]
```